# Setting branch restriction in bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

I have a use-case as described below,

Set only read-access to the user that to for a particular branch.  For example i have qa-branch and production-branch.  I want to set permission to a particular user for a particular branch.
I am able to see restriction for write access only.  What about read access?

Any help.

Answer (score 0):

The "write access" list on a branch permission setting is additive; only the people who are on that list are permitted to write to the specified branch(es). Leave that user off the "write access" list, and they will have read-only access to that branch.